# Get data fields from space-separated and quote-enclosed elements in string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, split

To handle an api response I need to first split a string into separate string fields. The number of fields are fixed (each always present), but an "empty" field may be represented as `?` or `""`. Terminated by `\n`. A single field may or may not be contained within two escaped quotes, but only the eight field may contain spaces and other characters like / % ? :

`"A single field / % ?"`

and can also contain numbers or forward slashes, as shown below.

Example of two strings, each with 20 fields :

```
14 S 20 ? OSE ? NHY "Norsk Hydro" NO0005052605 1 "20180921" 48.6 2068998276 NOK S I ? ? 1 Y\n

40 S 20 ? OSE ? "" "Boa SBL AS 13/18 FRN C" NO0010675051 1 "20180706" 45 0 NOK B ? ? ? 0.01 Y\n
```

What would be a safe and efficient way to do this?

I see I can make it work, but it's just not very elegant..

Comment: @Richardissimo True, both corrected.

Comment: Understood now. Edited to show actual values.

Comment: Can a double quote mark itself be in a quoted string? Like "Norsk \"Hydro\"", or "Norsk ""Hydro"""?

Comment: @Dialecticus No, double quotes only used to encapsulate a full string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `Regex` to find things along these lines (you'd need to do a bit more work for the quoted values)...

```
var value = @"14 S 20 ? OSE ? NHY ""Norsk Hydro"" NO0005052605 1 ""20180921"" 48.6 2068998276 NOK S I ? ? 1 Y"+"\n";
var pattern = new Regex(@"^(""(.*?)""|[^ ""]+)( (""(.*?)""|[^ ""]+)){19,19}\n$");
var match = pattern.Match(value);
if (match.Success)
{
    for (int ctr = 1; ctr < match.Groups.Count; ctr++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("   Group {0}:  {1}", ctr, match.Groups[ctr].Value);
        int captureCtr = 0;
        foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups[ctr].Captures)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("      Capture {0}: {1}",
                captureCtr, capture.Value);
            captureCtr++;
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you want a non-Regex solution: use `string.Split` using space, into a `Queue<string>`s constructor, and then process the queue in a loop, `Dequeue`ing each item at a time.

If the item started with `\"` then have another loop `Dequeue`ing into a `List<string>` until the corresponding item ending with close quote, at which point, reconstruct the quoted value by using `string.Join(" ", list)`.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the "inner" patterns now (the meaning of A,B,C,D in `@"^(A|B)( (C|D)){19,19}\n$"`). But may you please explain how far each of those inner pattern matches, and do the groups refer back to the order of these inner patterns? For example I don't understand why simply `@"^(A|B){19,19}\n$"` wouldn't work.

Comment: You have 20 items in your list, so I've defined the Regex as "an item" (quoted, or not quoted) followed by 19 instances of "<space> followed by an item". The "Groups" refer to the normal brackets in the Regex (except for Group zero, which represents the entire match, so I skipped it). The captures represent the individual instances of that group which where found.